# Rails Contact form, Action_mailer not sending e-mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, contact-form

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong.

I see that quite many people have similar problems:
 [Rails contact form not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185483/rails-contact-form-not-working),
 [Rails 3 Contact Form, undefined method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161364/rails-3-contact-form-undefined-method),
 [Contact Us form in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720409/contact-us-form-in-rails-3) and etc.

Even tough I also see that quite many consider this very simple - to build a contact form.
Been trough popular actionmailer guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html,
http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

I am not really a developer, so I find this quite confusing.

Anyway, I need to build a simple contact form, to just send the message as an email for a email account of mine. I don't want to store the messages in my db.

Here's my code:

/app/models/message.rb

```
  class Message
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    extend ActiveModel::Naming

    attr_accessor :name, :email, :content


    def initialize(attributes = {})
     attributes.each do |name, value|
     send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

   def persisted?
    false
   end
  end
```

app\controllers\messages_controller.rb

```
 class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
   @message = Message.new(params[:message])
   MessageMailer.send(@message).deliver
   flash[:notice] = "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
   redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

/app/mailer/message_mailer.rb

```
  class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default :to => "emils.veveris@thrillengine.com"

    def send(message)
      @message = message
      mail( :subject => " Test ", :from => @message.email ) do |format|
      format.text
    end
  end
end
```

app/views/messages/new.html.erb

```
<h1> "Contact Us"  </h1>

  <%= form_for @message do |f| %>

  <p>
   <%= f.label :name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
   <%= f.label :email %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>

  <p>
  <%= f.label :content, "Message" %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Send Message" %></p>
 <% end %>
```

app/views/message_mailer/sent.text.erb

```
Message sent by <%= @message.name %>

<%= @message.content %>
```

and development.rb

```
N1::Application.configure do

    # Don't care if the mailer can't send
    config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

end
```

I don't see any errors in log file and I don't receive any error messages.
The mail is just not delivered.

Can You please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It's similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991932/sending-confirmation-emails-to-registered-users-in-ror-app-via-localhost/10994387

Answer (score 0):

This is a little old but maybe some of the concepts can help you...it's pretty much exactly what you're trying to do.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model